# HTML error when attempting to use image in the same folder

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a folder `Block` with the following files within...

```
Block
   index.js
   Block.js
   Block.scss
   Block_Image.png
```

Within the `Block.js` file, I attempt to grab and display the image with...

`<img src="Block_Image.png alt='Picture of block' />`

Why do I get a `404 Not Found` error when running it? Only the alt text appears where the image should be. I have tried using different file paths, and I get the same error every time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: add ./ in front of Block_image.png i.e. src="./Block_Image.png"

Comment: @LeshawnRice for some reason that does not work

Answer (score 1):

Hit F12 and check if something is blocking. If not. I would try to inspect and open image src in new tab, that will help us identifying the issues with the image url.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems your forgot an **"**. 
If you didn't, try this :

```
<img src="./Block_Image.png" alt='Picture of block' />
```

Comment: I have tried this, and I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using "Block/Block_Image.png" ?
If the html is on one level up, then it will look up in that folder.

Comment: Yes I have, and yes I still get the 404 error